# Search and replace using regular expressions

Tags: notepad++, regex

I want to edit the text:

```
appriskid = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
app_name = models.TextField()
identifier = models.CharField(max_length=150)
version = models.CharField(max_length=60, blank=True)
                .

                . 
                .
```

to:

```
appriskid = None, app_name = None, identifier = None, version = None .......
```

Comment: Do it in two steps: first replace everything on a line after a `=` by `None`, then merge the lines by searching for `\n` (extended syntax) and replacing it with `,`.

Comment: Thank you, Could you tell me the regex strings to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that in 2 steps, as Daniel Beck suggested:

1. **Search Mode: Regular expression**

   *Find what:* `=.*`

   *Replace with:* `= None,` ("None" + Comma + Space)
2. **Search Mode: Extended**

   *Find what:* `\r\n`

   *Replace with:*  (Empty)

Comment: Or you could do it in one step (`=.*\r\n` as the search term, replace with `= None, `), assuming you are using Notepad++ version >= 6. They introduced PCRE, and multiline regex, in version 6 (http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html).